# Do I put constants in database or use file to save it

Tags: php, mysql, constants, codeigniter-2

Is that better to use database or file to save constants in my project? 
Which is fastest? 
I am programing a webpage in Codeigniter framework and site would have a multilanguage interface. These constants must be in that languages.

Comment: if you're going to be using the constants in conjunction with your database records, I would suggest placing them in a single row database. Allows you to write triggers and procedures directly.

Comment: No, it's a key value pairs with: language,key, key to diferent group of constants, translate a key. I use it in select list or in radio butons.

Comment: I think file is better and faster. I use Smarty with CI and I use {config_load } in the master template to load the strings. I load en version first and the display language after, s.t. strings NOT translated in the localized version will have the value from the English version. The display language is populated into data in Controller before rendering the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends also on who and when would change that constants. For example, if it is language strings and you would need to add new language in the future, it would be more convenient to store it in database and have some administration panel to edit/add them easily. Cause I had problems when I use default CodeIgniter Language functions and then got an Excel file from client with translations - had to copy-paste everything by hand in lang.php file.

If you don't need adding languages in the future or unlikely to change constants - then yeah, config files would be better. And you could load different configs from /config folder for different languages, if you want to.